# How to add a sub menu in Account Configuration Menu on OpenERP

Tags: configuration, submenu, account, openerp-7

I try to add a new menu in Account Configuration!

**Configuration**

- Periods
- Journals
- Accounts
- Taxes

-------> my menu

- Financial Reports
- Miscellaneo

So i use >> Parent="base.menu_config" but it's appear in Sale Configuration !!!

This is my code

```
<menuitem id="withholding_tax_type_menu" 
                            name="Withholding Tax Types"
                            parent="base.menu_config"
                            action="withholding_tax_type_action"/>  
</data>
```

Some one please help me and thank you for you time to reading my word :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,  Give Proper name as your module related. And you will get this. following is an example.

```
#create tree view and form view and below is menu

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_menu_tax_types">
    <field name="name">Withholding Tax Types</field>
    <field name="res_model">model.name</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>

<menuitem parent="account.next_id_27" id="menu_action_menu_tax_types" action="action_menu_tax_types"/>
```

You will see the below `Taxes Menu` like menu name `Tax Types` and sub menu name `Withholding Tax Types`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much Odedra it's can help me a lot,
i can see a new menu "Tax Types" and sub menu "Withholding Tax Type",
and can i have more question ??? 
- Is It Possible to add sub menu "Withholding Tax Type" into menu "Taxs"

Comment: Configuration - Periods - Journals - Accounts - Taxes - Financial Reports - Miscellaneo All of menu it's already have in menu "Account Configuration", right? So, i want to add sub menu "Withholding Tax Type" into menu "Taxes"

Comment: yes, i edited my answer please try that and you will get menu below Taxes => Taxes

Comment: but it's appear in Taxes=> Taxes Code=> "Withholding Tax Type" | 
i want to add in Taxes==> Withholding Tax Type
Thank you so much, Odedra :D

Comment: Ohkk I edited my answer and Your question requirement and you ask new in comment. So Please first clear and ask question. So easy to handle and if your problem is solved than accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: I already have my sub menu in Taxes because of you Odedra :))
I'm so sorry about that and next time i will waiting 
Thank you for your time you helping a lot

Comment: Thank you. Accept the answer. Fill the Right Symbol. if you don't know how to accept that take tour of Stackoverflow. At in help menu in your right hand side.